# How to convert server time to local time in Laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, time, timezone

I would like to print the time in local time in Laravel. If the user create a post it will display the created time on the server. How can I display it in local time ?

In my blade file I used this code to display created time,

```
{{{ $posts->updated_at }}}
```

Which displays the time in database, which is a server time. How can I convert it to users local time ?

Comment: Your basic options are 1) Do this client-side, where you have better information about the time zone; make your response contain the UTC timestamp in some JSON, and then write Javascript to display that timestamp in local time; 2) Tell the server which time zone the user is in (which can be somewhat tricky in itself) and perform the conversion at the server side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution to convert time to local time by using session. The current time zone offset will store on session to calculate users time. Create a jquery post function to post users timezone offset to session. This is my code,

**default.blade.php**

```
@if($current_time_zone=Session::get('current_time_zone'))@endif
<input type="hidden" id="hd_current_time_zone" value="{{{$current_time_zone}}}">
// For assigning session value to hidden field. 

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      if($('#hd_current_time_zone').val() ==""){ // Check for hidden field is empty. if is it empty only execute the post function
          var current_date = new Date();
          curent_zone = -current_date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
          var token = "{{csrf_token()}}";
          $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "{{URL::to('ajax/set_current_time_zone/')}}",
            data: {  '_token':token, curent_zone: curent_zone } 
          }).done(function( data ){
        });   
      }       
});
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('ajax/set_current_time_zone', array('as' => 'ajaxsetcurrenttimezone','uses' => 'HomeController@setCurrentTimeZone'));
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function setCurrentTimeZone(){ //To set the current timezone offset in session
    $input = Input::all();
    if(!empty($input)){
        $current_time_zone = Input::get('curent_zone');
        Session::put('current_time_zone',  $current_time_zone);
    }
}
```

**Helpers/helper.php**

```
function niceShort($attr) {
    if(Session::has('current_time_zone')){
       $current_time_zone = Session::get('current_time_zone');
       $utc = strtotime($attr)-date('Z'); // Convert the time zone to GMT 0. If the server time is what ever no problem.

       $attr = $utc+$current_time_zone; // Convert the time to local time
       $attr = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $attr);
    }
    return attr;
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
{{ niceShort($posts->updated_at) }}
```

Now we can print the time in clients time zone. The time zone setting code run only when the session empty.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using javascript. Use following libraries:

1. moment.min.js (http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js)
2. moment-timezone-with-data.js ()
3. jstz.min.js (https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect)

Here is the code :

```
var update_at = '<?php echo $posts->updated_at;?>'; //set js variable for updated_at
var serverTimezone = 'YOUR SERVER TIME ZONE'; //set js variable for server timezone
var momentJsTimeObj = moment.tz(update_at, serverTimezone); //create moment js time object for server time
var localTimeZone = jstz.determine(); //this will fetch user's timezone
var localTime = momentJsTimeObj.clone().tz(localTimeZone.name()).format(); //convert server time to local time of user
```

Now you can display local time through js

Answer (score 2):

Try this method, I think this is what you want:

```
$localTime = $object->created_at->timezone($this->auth->user()->timezone);
```

Here, `$this->auth->user()->timezone` will return current user's timezone, and `timezone()` will convert `created_at` to to user's local time.

If you want to get all visitors timezone (not just logged in users), you can you package for Laravel similar to [laravel-geoip](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip). It will generate `$visitor['timezone']` for you which you can use like this:

```
$localTime = $object->created_at->timezone($visitor['timezone']);
```

Comment: No change, It will display the same time

Comment: How exactly are trying to use it? Can you show full code?

Comment: invalid answer i am afraid. this would only work if there is such a column in the users table called timezone or a method returning the desired data. Laravel out of box does not record a registered user's geo-location and in turn timezone.

Answer (score 2):

Best option is to do this with Javascript, get client's timezone and then convert server time to cleint's accordingly.

Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1837243/4007628

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$dt = new DateTime($posts->updated_at);
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'); // or whatever zone you're after

$dt->setTimezone($tz);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: By using this code we can convert the time to only GMT +5.30. The date will show in any location

Comment: you mean as per user location you want to convert it?

Comment: Yes @vipul sorathiya

Comment: I think this will helpfull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203382/how-to-automatically-detect-users-timezone

Answer (score 1):

Go to app.php page in Config folder and change this

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

to

```
'timezone' => 'addYourTimeZoneHere',
```

reference
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration

find your timezone
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

Server time should stick with UTC timezone

In front end, you can use moment.js to render the correct local timezone. I tested this in moment version 2.22.2.

Simply add Z to the datetime value and moment will render the date to user's local time zone

```
moment(dateTimeValue + ' Z');
```

Answer (score -3):

Comment the timezone settings in app.php page

```
//'timezone' => 'UTC',
```